# How to refresh a component after uploading file successfully

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm encountering an issue where I need to refresh a parent component (Component A) in React after successfully uploading a file in a child component (Component B). Here's the breakdown of my setup:

Scenario:

Component A is the parent component, and Component B is the child component.
Component B contains the file upload section along with the upload button.
Upon successful file upload, I aim to clear the values from five dropdown fields in Component A.

Current Approach:

I've attempted to clear the state values in Component A using a function (`clearDataForm`), which increments a key state to trigger a refresh.

Problem:

Although I can clear the state values successfully, the dropdown fields don't refresh automatically because their values are populated from an API. Therefore, I need to refresh the page to repopulate these dropdown values.

```
    // Parent Component - A
    const [key, setKey] = useState(0);
    
    const clearDataForm = () => {
      setKey(prevKey => prevKey + 1);
    }
    
    <Form>
      <FormData.Group>
        {/* Field One */}
      </FormData.Group>
      {/* Other fields */}
    
      {/* FileUpload from Component B */}
      <FileUpload uploadedData={uplodDetails} clearDataForm={() => clearDataForm()}/>
    </Form>
    
    // Component - B
    const handleFileUpload = async (uploadedFile) => {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", uploadedFile);
    
      try {
        const res = await API.uploadFiled(Add_Uploaded_File_Fields, id, formData);
        if (response?.status === 200) {
          clearDataForm();
          toast.success("Uploaded");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle error
      }
    }
```

Objective:

I'm seeking a solution to refresh Component A automatically after a successful file upload in Component B, ensuring that the dropdown fields reflect the updated state without requiring a manual page refresh.
Any assistance or guidance on achieving this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to show us how the dropodown values are being set/rendered. If your goal is to have them not render, then consider using some sort of state in the parent that you set (via thee child) once the file has been uploaded, and then use that state to control if the dropdown values appear or not.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the dropdown fields refresh after clearing the state, you need to fetch the data again from the API after clearing the state

In this approach, whenever the file upload in Component B is successful, the clearDataForm function from Component A is called to clear the state, which triggers a re-render of Component A due to the change in the key state. After the state is cleared, the useEffect hook in Component A refetches the dropdown data from the API, ensuring that the dropdown fields are updated with the latest data.

Try if this helps.

Component A:

```
  const ComponentA = () => {
  const [key, setKey] = useState(0);
  const [dropdownData, setDropdownData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch dropdown data from API when component mounts
    fetchData();
  }, [key]); // Fetch data whenever the key state changes

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      // Fetch dropdown data from API
      const response = await API.fetchDropdownData();
      if (response?.status === 200) {
        // Set dropdown data in state
        setDropdownData(response.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  const clearDataForm = () => {
    // Increment key to trigger refresh
    setKey(prevKey => prevKey + 1);
  };

  return (
    <Form>
      <FormData.Group>
        {/* Render dropdown fields with data */}
        {dropdownData.map(item => (
          <FormData.DropDown key={item.id} options={item.options} />
        ))}
      </FormData.Group>
      {/* Other fields */}
      <FileUpload clearDataForm={clearDataForm} />
    </Form>
  );
};
```

Component B:

```
const FileUpload = ({ clearDataForm }) => {
  const handleFileUpload = async (uploadedFile) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", uploadedFile);
    
    try {
      const res = await API.uploadFiled(Add_Uploaded_File_Fields, id, formData);
      if (res?.status === 200) {
        // Call clearDataForm function passed from parent
        clearDataForm();
        toast.success("Uploaded");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  return (
    // Render file upload section
    // Pass handleFileUpload function to your file upload component
  );
};
```